# Promise not executing

Tags: javascript, promise

Promise not executing as expected. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, the then after promise all never executes.

```
exports.handler = (event, database, defaultBucket) => {
  if( event.data.val() ){
    const { userId, postId } = event.params;
    createFolderInTmp(postId);
    return event.data.ref.parent.once("value", ((snap) => {
      //getpostData data
      const postData = snap.val();
      var downloadPromises = [];
      const images = [];
      postData.slides.forEach(slide => {
          images.push(slide.value);
      });
      return Promise.all([
            ...images.map((image) => {
              return downloadImageAsync(image, postId, defaultBucket);
            })
          ])
       .then(() => {
//-----NEVER EXECUTES THIS STEP, SIMPLY GOES BLANK HERE----
          createAGIF(postData, postId);
          return console.log('this completed');
       })
       .then(() => {
          return uploadImageAsync( getLocalGIFFilePath(postId), getDestinationUrl(userId, postId) ,'image/gif',defaultBucket)
       })
       .then(() => {
          return updateShareableUrl(userId, postId, defaultBucket);
       });
    }));
  }else{
    console.log('No Data available');
    return false;
  }
};
```

Adding related functions

```
function downloadImageAsync(imageUrl, storyId, bucket){
   const tempFilePath = getTempDownloadUrl(storyId, encodeURIComponent(imageUrl));
   return bucket.file(imageUrl).download({ destination: tempFilePath});
}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you handling possible errors anywhere? Also does `once` really take a promise-returning callback function?

Comment: You  really really should never use `[...x.map(…)]`. Just `x.map(…)` is enough.

Comment: I have literally tried everything, destructuring and applying a map is pointless, but thats not the problem here

Comment: Can you show us the code for `downloadImageAsync()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about this in the wrong way. The moment `event.data.ref.parent.once` resolves, the job of this function is done, and whatever I return from inside the callback, does not matter anymore. The function execution stops. The resources are deallocated. It was not until Bergi pointed out of handling errors, but in this case there were no errors.

Comment: I don't think it's `once` that somehow "stops its callback" - that doesn't happen in JS - but rather that when the promise you're returning from the export resolves, google-cloud-functions kills the process.

Comment: thing of this, function x returned y which was again a promise, that is not being handled in firebase functions is what I see